# Why doesn't DbSets work when initialized as a field, rather than as a property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

For some reason when you do something like `DbSet<TSource> blabla;` rather than `DbSet <TSource> Property_Blabla {get; set;}` , when doing migrations it never understands or spots the DbSets? Why is that the case, can someone clarify?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because EF was designed that way.  I can speculate that it's because using fields instead of properties is generally considered bad practice.  Or that it would complicate the design and confuse developers.  So adding the ability to use fields wouldn't be worth the effort.

But there's no fundamental reason that entities are declared using properties of type `DbSet<T>` instead of some other convention.